# Encoding Video files for sending over TCP Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-server

Hello I have a basic python 3 Ubuntu server set up and am wanting to send .h264 video or .jpeg images over from a Raspberry Pi Client.  The Raspberry Pi is using the Official Camera V2.  I am unable to find information on how to save from a client to my TCP server and was wondering what the best method would be.  The Raspberry Pi is setup to only begin recording once motion has been detected.  My server works well with a temperature sensor and flood sensor but I would like to be able to save and use the video to be messaged to a cell phone eventually, I hope this clears things up.
-Thanks
Raspberry Pi client

```
import picamera
import picamera.array
import time

threshold = 10
sensitivity = 100

def takeMotionImage(width, height):
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        time.sleep(1)
        camera.resolution = (width, height)
        with picamera.array.PiRGBArray(camera) as stream:
            camera.exposure_mode = 'auto'
            camera.awb_mode = 'auto'
            camera.capture(stream, format='rgb')
            return stream.array

def scanMotion(width, height):
    motionFound = False
    data1  = takeMotionImage(width, height)
    while not motionFound:
        data2 = takeMotionImage(width, height)
        diffCount = 0;
        for w in range(0, width):
            for h in range(0, height):

            diff = abs(int(data1[h][w][1]) - int(data2[h][w][1]))
            if diff > threshold:
                diffCount += 1
        if diffCount > sensitivity:
            break;
    if diffCount > sensitivity:
        motionFound = True
    else:
        data2 = data1
return motionFound

def motionDetection():
print ("Scanning for Motion threshold=%i sensitivity=%i..." % (threshold, sensitivity))
while True:
    if scanMotion(224, 160):
        camera = picamera.PiCamera()
        stream = picamera.PiCameraCircularIO(camera, seconds=20)
        camera.start_recording(stream, format='h264')
        print ("Motion detected")
        camera.wait_recording(1)
        camera.wait_recording(10)
        stream.copy_to('AFeed.h264')
        print ('Written To File')
        camera.stop_recording()
        print ('Camera Stopped')            
if __name__ == '__main__':
try:
    motionDetection()
finally:
    print ("Exiting Program")
```

TCP Server

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn
from twilio.rest import Client

floodtest01 = 'True'
account_sid = 'EMPTY'
auth_token = 'EMPTY'

myPhone = 'EMPTY'
TwilioNumber = 'Empty'

x = 0
y = 0
z = 0

class ClientThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,ip,port):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        print ("[+] New thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(2048)
            data = data.decode('utf-8')
            client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
            if data == floodtest01:
                print ('There is a flood!')
                global z
                while z == 0:
                    print ('This is a flooding test!')
                    client.message.creater(
                        to=myPhone,
                        from_=TwilioNumber,
                        body='There is a flood alert!'
                    )
                    z = z + 1
            elif data.count('.') == 1:
                temp = float(data)
                temp = round(temp, 3)
                temp = (((temp * 9/5) + 32) - 17.8)
                if temp >= 86:
                    print ('We have a high temperature of: ', temp)
                    global x
                   while x == 0:
                        print ('This is a high temperature test: ', temp)
                        client.messages.create(
                            to=myPhone,
                           from_=TwilioNumber,
                            body='There is a high temperature alert!'
                        )
                        x = x + 1
                elif temp <= 62:
                    print ('We have a low temperature of: ', temp)
                    global y
                    while y == 0:
                        print ('This is a low temperature test: ', temp)
                        client.messages.create(
                            to=myPhone,
                            from_=TwilioNumber,
                            body='There is a low temperature alert!'
                        )
                        y = y + 1
                else:
                    print ('We do not have a temperature problem! ' , temp)

            elif not data:
                   break
            print ("received data:", data)
            data = data.encode('utf-8')
            conn.send(data)

TCP_IP = '0.0.0.0'
TCP_PORT = 21567
BUFFER_SIZE = 20

tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcpsock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
threads = []

while True:
    tcpsock.listen(4)
    print ("Waiting for incoming connections...")
    (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpsock.accept()
    newthread = ClientThread(ip,port)
    newthread.start()
    threads.append(newthread)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: It seems unlikely that anyone has packaged up an h264 encoded as a codec.  encode and decode are oriented more towards things like utf-8 and base64.  Your question is very broadly framed, though, and there are a lot of things you _might_ be interested in.  Can you limit the scope a bit?  And explain what you've already researched and attempted and any specific problems you've encountered.

Comment: I have attempted to stream the video to my server using the code in the official pi camera docs using this program http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.9/recipes1.html#recording-to-a-network-stream but I need to be able to process when a file is recording if I am using motion detection as a condition before video is supposed to be sent, and I need to steam it over to my server then maybe send some kind of text alert with the video or images from the video to a cell phone.  That is where I am stuck because most website just go into the streaming part.  I hope I focused the question more

Comment: You can edit the extra information into the question itself.  I still don't have a good idea of what you're stuck on.  This is a programming website.  Therefore, I suppose, you're trying to write a program.  And you've having difficulty with some aspect of that task.  The overall design?  Use of a specific library?  Implementation of a certain operation?  What?  And what kind of trouble?  And what have you tried to resolve this trouble?